# With respect to grammas, when are eplison production rules allowed?

Tags: grammar, epsilon

I'm trying to understand a concept with respect to grammar and Production Rules.

According to most material on this subject:

1) Epsilon production rules are only allowable if they do not appear on the RHS of any other production rule.

However, taking a grammar:

```
G = { T,N,P,S }
```

Where:

```
T = {a,b}
N = {S,S1}
S = {S}
P { 
    S -> aSb
    S -> ab
    S1 -> SS1
    S1 -> E         //Please note, using E to represent Epsilon.
  }
```

Where, the language of the grammar is:

```
L(G) = { a^n, b^n | n >= 1 }
```

In this case, a production rule containing Epsilon exists (derived from S1) but S1 also forms part of a RHS of another production rule (S1 -> SS1).

Doesn't this violate point 1?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chomsky_hierarchy#The_hierarchy

Answer (score 1):

Your statement:

> Epsilon production rules are only allowable if they do not appear on the RHS of any other production rule.

would be better stated as

> A non-terminal may have an epsilon production rules if that non-terminal does not appear on the right-hand side of any production rule.

In Chomsky's original hierarchy, epsilon productions were banned for all but Type 0 (unrestricted) grammars. If all epsilon productions are banned, then it is impossible for the grammar to produce the empty string. I believe this was not a concern for Chomsky; consequently, most modern formulations allow the start symbol to have an empty right-hand side as long as the start symbol itself does not appear on the right-hand side of any production.

As it happens, the restriction on epsilon-productions is somewhat stronger than is necessary. In the case of both context-free grammars and regular grammars (Chomsky type 2 and type 3 grammars), it is always possible to create a weakly-equivalent grammar without epsilon productions (except possibly the single production *S* → ε if the grammar can produce the empty string.) It is also possible to remove a number of other anomalies which complicate grammar analysis: unreachable symbols, unproductive symbols, and cyclic productions. The result of the combination of all these eliminations is a "proper context-free grammar".

Consequently, most modern formulations of context-free grammars do not require the right-hand sides to be non-empty.

Your grammar *G* = {*T*, *N*, *S*, *P*} with

- *T* = {*a*, *b*}
- *N* = {*S*, *S*<sub>1</sub>}
- *S* = {*S*}
- *P* { 
    *S* → *a* *S* *b*
    *S* → *a* *b*
    *S*<sub>1</sub> → *S* *S*<sub>1</sub>
    *S*<sub>1</sub> → ε
  }

contains an unreachable symbol, *S*<sub>1</sub>. We can easily eliminate it, producing the equivalent grammar *G'* = { *T*, *N'*, *S*, *P'* }:

- *N'* = {*S*}
- *P'* { 
    *S* → *a* *S* *b*
    *S* → *a* *b*
  }

*G'* does not contain any epsilon productions (but even if it had, they could have been [eliminated](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2010/02/08/removing-epsilon-productions-from-context-free-grammars)).